# Use jQuery to make a navigation arrow appear for a particular image in a set of images

Tags: jquery

I have a "vertical" image gallery of this sort:

```
<div class="image-container>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="next"><a href="info"><img src="arrow_trans.png" alt="Next" /></a>  
    </div>    

    <div id="vert-gallery">
        <div id="first-row" class="link-image"><img src="Image_1.png" /></div>
        <div id="second-row" class="link-image"><img src="Image_2.png" /></div>
        <div id="third-row" class="link-image"><img src="Image_3.png" /></div>
        <div id="first-row" class="link-image"><img src="Image_4.png" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I hover over any one of these images, I want a navigation arrow to appear. I've been using:

```
$(".link-image").hover(function() {
    $("div.nav").show();
    },

        function() {
    $("div.nav").hide();
});
```

This makes the navigation arrow appear over all the images (since they're of the same class).

How can I make it only appear over the image I'm hovering over and not the other ones?

**Edit**

In my case, `div.nav` is part of `image-container`. I might have multiple containers on the same page.

Comment: where is the div with class nav?

Comment: I've edited the code. It leads to the same place currently. This is a practice run.

Comment: HTML you provided wouldn't make `div.nav` to display 4 times (at the same time). Please provide a working example in JSFiddle. Your HTML is probably different or you have other scripts that do things differently.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. This is a slightly more complex problem than I've showed on screen. Let me edit the question. You'll have to bear with me a bit.

Comment: @Robert: Found the answer but what you pointed out helped me realise the minor change I needed to make to get the final solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the selectors should work if the nav div is inside each of the link-image divs.

```
$(".link-image").hover(function() {
        $("div.nav", this).show();
    },
    function() {
        $("div.nav", this).hide();
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/87ngB/)

Comment: But your HTML is making some assumptions we don't know... And based on his HTML are invalid (even though his HTML and script wouldn't work as he describes anyway).

Comment: @Robert - That is true, although he hadn't posted the full html when I answered so I had to make some assumptions.

Comment: A bit of rejigging and this did exactly what I needed! Could you please explain how using `this` where you did, helps?

Comment: @Az The second parameter in a selector specifies the context that the selector should use. So in this case, it only looks for 'div.nav' inside the element that you have hovered over. It is really the same as doing `$(this).find('div.nav')` but I think it looks nicer.

Comment: It's concise yet still makes sense - a bit of a novelty I'd have to say. I hazarded a guess as to what it was doing but wanted to be certain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` keyword inside the hover callback (or any callback for that matter), to target the element whose currently been hovered.

If the `div.nav` is a decendent of all `.link-image` elements, you might prefer something like this:

```
$('.link-image').bind('mouseover', function () {
    $('div.nav').hide(); // hide all div.nav elements.

    $(this).find('div.nav').show(); // show the one for the current mouse-overed element. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the this keyword, it will refer to the current object that passed the event. (I Could be wrong, correct me if I am).

Have a read at http://api.jquery.com/hover/

So you could use, but it depends on you hiding all the images to begin with:

```
$(".link-image").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
    },

        function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

**NOTE: I HAVEN'T TESTED THIS CODE**